# how to send a image path from php

Tags: php, image, jpeg

I have to write a php application (let us call it imagepath.php) to support a iphone/ipad app.

Imagepath.php needs to return path to an image example   www.xyz.com/whatever/image.jpeg

In imagepath.php I am successfully able to get correct image path from 
Here is an example: http://cdn.svcs.x.y.com/c2/37a86590e709012e2fb300163e41dd5b

If I send this path as it is to iphone/ipad app it does not work, but if i send it a proper image path such as  www.xyz.com/whatever/image.jpeg it works fine.

How do I fix it?

My current code

```
<?php
..
..
..
// With some code above I am able to get image path in remote_img 
$remote_img = $results[1][0];
//send image out
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo(file_get_contents($remote_img));
?>
```

Here is a sample image path that comes to $remote_img
http://cdn.svcs.c2.uclick.com/c2/37a86590e709012e2fb300163e41dd5b

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! To solve your problem without resorting to a crystall ball, we need to see your current code (ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)). Additionally, an example URL demoing the problem would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as is, as long as `$remote_img` is correct when you do the `file_get_contents()`

Comment: it is not working. But if I send a fixed image path with .jpg ending it works fine.

Comment: You could use CURL or something and actually see why it's not fetching the file.

Comment: As app is expecting a JPEG link. Is it possible to create a temporary image and send link of it? If so how to do it? How to delete temporary image?